# Dateime Parse method adding one day to input date

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I am reading a date from an xml file and parsing it to a my desired format. It i adding a day to the date and i cant seem to figure out why.

input : 2014-02-12T15:21:19-08:00
output : 13 Feb 2014 01:21

Here is my code to parse date:

```
string date = DateTime.Parse(row["CountDate"].ToString()).ToString("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is that `-08:00` in the input ?

Comment: Seems like 08:00 is added to your date.

Comment: @Ofiris It seems that it is the timezone (GMT) in which the datetime is being stored. I guess LuckyLuke2 is in GMT+2, so the output is correct (I am in GMT+1 so it displays "13 Feb 2014 00:21").

Comment: @Styxxy yes that is correct.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that the timezone information is being used to adjust the time to your local time zone.

If you remove the "-08:00" suffix, you'll find that the time won't be adjusted. However, you need to know whether the timezone information is important before ignoring it!

Comment: Although that will stop the adjustment, this will prevent the user from discovering the local time (which may be important).

Comment: @James That's true, and so you should keep the timezone information. I was just explaining what was happening.

Answer (score 2):

Well it looks like what you have is a UTC date/time with an 8 hour offset, when you parse the date what you have is an instance of the *local* time (`Parse` will take into account the offset).

If you are only interested in the UTC date/time then you can parse just that particular information

```
DateTime.ParseExact("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", row["CountDate"], 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```